# Highlighting the details of middle UserControl Item of a wp7 ListBox as shown in Image

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1.1

[image: Listbox highlighting middle item]

I am having a Horizontal listbox having usercontrol(150 width and 150 height as dimensions) as items.

I am displaying 3 items in listbox at a time. My question is how can I detect the middle item while scrolling so that as i scroll left or right i can display the name and other details of middle listbox item in texblock placed above it.

Please refer the image uploaded.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @MattLacey I am not sure I was thinking of getting the visible items on listbox but I am not sure how can we fetch those objects and how to select one element or position in listbox programmatically...Please put light on this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this
http://silverlightcarousel.codeplex.com/

http://wpfcarousel.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're looking for a CoverFlow control. I know [ComponentOne](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/CoverFlowPhone/) have one and there are probably others.

If this is for a commercial app it'll definitely be easier to buy one than build your own.

If you're all set on building your own then you'll probably want to build from scratch as the ListBox doesn't allow for the customization you'll require.

Comment: Hi @Matt as this app will be free so I cant go for paid controls. Moreover animation of middle item is not essential thing for me, even getting the middle object attached with list item will do the job. I am only concerned with showing details of middle object. Can we achieve with simple Listbox. Thanks for getting back.

Comment: Doing this with a ListBox will be really hard. You're going to have to ask yourself how much your time is worth