# How to fetch Listbox middle item as soon as stop the horizontally scrolling in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, listbox

I am facing some issue regarding retrieve Listbox middle item details. I am binding some Images and name on that images Horizontally In  Listbox. When I scroll the listbox horizontally I need to fetch middle image name.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Horizontal Looping Selector](http://blog.supaywasi.com/2011/06/horizontal-looping-selector/) which can be used by installing [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/)

EDIT:

As you mentioned in the comments. Here is what you can do. This code will detect how much each element is visible on the screen. Using this get the elements which are visible on screen and so the middle element.

```
private void FindVisibleItems(ListBox listbox) 
    { 
        var listboxRectangle = new Rect(new Point(0, 0), listbox.RenderSize); 
        for (int index = 0; index < listbox.Items.Count; index++) 
        { 
            double visiblePercent = 0; 

            ListBoxItem item = listbox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index) as ListBoxItem; 
            if (item != null) 
            { 
                var itemTransform = item.TransformToVisual(listbox); 
                var itemRectangle = itemTransform.TransformBounds(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), item.RenderSize)); 
                itemRectangle.Intersect(listboxRectangle); 

                if (!itemRectangle.IsEmpty) 
                { 
                    visiblePercent = itemRectangle.Height / item.RenderSize.Height * 100; 
                } 
            } 

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Item {0}: {1}% visible", index, Math.Round(visiblePercent))); 
        } 
    }
```

Reference: [Get the first and last visible element of widows phone listbox](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/44a17ea7-e807-43b3-973f-e2cff4a48630/get-the-first-and-last-visible-element-of-widows-phone-listbox?forum=wpdevelop)

Comment: Hello Akshay ,Thank you very much your reply. Horizontal Looping Selector is not suitable for my requirement.I need to develop like Please check folowing link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134718/highlighting-the-details-of-middle-usercontrol-item-of-a-wp7-listbox-as-shown-in
In Windows phone 8 I need to develop.Any Help?

Comment: That could be done with [Carousel control](http://help.syncfusion.com/UG/Windows%20Phone%208/index.html#!Documents/carousel.htm) from Syncfusion Essential Studio. If you are an individual or a small business you will get [Syncfusion community Edition license](https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/communitylicense) for free.

Comment: Hi Aksha,can you send me your mail id why bz I will send you screen shot which i am doing Now. So you can Come to know what is My Requirement.So please?

Comment: Add image to your question so that other people can also help. Edit it and add the screenshot.

Comment: Please have a look below shared Image.Here I binding all Data.Based on Some Height, I am adjusting Image(Which having Red Color) Height and binding it horizontally in Listbox also I am Binding Text which contains Height in percentage.Please Check Image Link.

http://i.stack.imgur.com/ligWN.png

Now I will scroll Horizontally and I will stop Scrolling then I need to Get which is Middle position.See in second image,there 0% value is in middle position so now i need to get that value.

Check Image 2: http://i.stack.imgur.com/VSCWk.png

Now How to do like this?

Comment: Akshay,I called this code in Listbox ManipulationStarted event.But I am not getting clear Answer in the sense Here
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Item {0}: {1}% visible", index, Math.Round(visiblePercent)));
I am getting Index is last Index of Listbox Item But I have to Get Middle Item.

Comment: You will get the index of all items present on the screen. Get the average of first and last element and that will be the middle element

Comment: Thank you Akshay.I will check it out.